# Group listview that have the data from sql

Tags: c#, listview

I have written a code that take data from SQL to listview. 
[[here screenshot of the data pulled and shown on listview.
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6j8M.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6j8M.png)

How i can create a group on this list view using the headid.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Timers;
namespace AbhiProject{
public partial class daybook_credit : Form
{
    public daybook_credit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindGrid();
    }
    //int ID = 0;
    private SqlConnection con;
    private SqlCommand cmd;
    private SqlDataAdapter adapt;
    private DataTable dt;
    //Connection String
    string cs = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Abhilash\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\db_all.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
    private void BindGrid()
    {
        listView1.GridLines = true;
        listView1.View = View.Details;

        //Add Column Header

        listView1.Columns.Add("ID", 50);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Head ID", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Date", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Receipt No", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Details", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Cash Credit", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Transfer Credit Adjustment", 150);

        con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();


        // Chnage sql query and table name
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from daybook_credit ORDER BY headid ASC", con);
        SqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        listView1.Items.Clear();

        while (Reader.Read())
        {

            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { Reader.GetInt32(0).ToString(), Reader.GetInt32(1).ToString(), Reader.GetString(2), Reader.GetString(3), Reader.GetString(4), Reader.GetInt32(5).ToString(), Reader.GetInt32(6).ToString() }, Reader.GetInt32(1).ToString()));



        }
        //MessageBox.Show(Reader.GetInt32(1).ToString());

        Reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }

}}
```

how do i group this data,also i want to know is it possible to find the sum of cash credit for each group

Comment: The `DataGridView` is always a much better choice for  displaying DB data.  No need to add columns or even rows; best of all the data is not all strings so you can manage the data properly

Comment: but grouping not possible on DataGridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you cannot directly do grouping on the gridview,

Instead, create a custom **`class`** as per your requirement,

```
public class Sample
{
 public float TransferCredit { get; set; }
 public float CashCredit { get; set; }
 public DateTime Date { get; set; }
 public int HeadID { get; set; }
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public int RecieptNo { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the same and fill the List

```
List<Sample> result = new List<Sample>();
while (Reader.Read())
  {
   var Sample = new Sample
   {
     TransferCredit = reader.GetInt32(0),
     CashCredit = reader.GetString(1)
      ......
   }
 result.Add(foo);
}
```

Then you can do the **[`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx)** using linq

```
 result.GroupBy(t => t.HeadID);
```

And bing the result.